# Two J-1 programs during one stay?

Tags: j1-visas

I'm a German PhD student invited to a 4-week internship to the U.S. next year. It's a small software company, which is very closely attached to academia (scientific software, professors on the company board and so on). Additionally, I also got invited for two 2-week research visits in the groups of two professors attached to the company just prior to the internship. These two visits would also be at two different U.S. universities.

During the whole eight weeks I would not receive any salary or stipend but only reimbursements. The problem is that the first four weeks fit more to a J-1 *research scholar* program and the last four weeks would be better described by a J-1 *intern* program.

Is it possible to come to the U.S. on one J-1 visa but two different programs?

Can the DS-2019 form be transferred or "updated" to the current location/program?

I'm aware this is a unusual situation and useful information from government pages is very hard to come by. I definitely appreciate any information which helps clarify my situation.

Comment: Unless the software company is in a position to host a research scholar, which is usually extended by a university, it would seem less complex, or confusing, to apply as an intern, with the company as the Designated Sponsor Organization. As you describe it, the company, and its affiliates, the professors are inviting you, not the university. In either event, the company/university has to document to the IRS all monies paid to non-resident aliens, including reimbursements.

Comment: You mentioned Designated Sponsor Organization, can the company be sponsor and host at the same time? I thought that's not possible...

Comment: Some are, such as Fermi Research, but the company can also participate through a DSO, such as the German American Chamber of Commerce. To your question, I don't see a conflict spending two weeks prior to the internship with the professors. There is a conflict, I would think, to have the university sponsor and then work for a company, unpaid, afterwards. However, be very careful; the US frowns on 'unpaid' internships, regardless of nationality, as potentially unfair or abusive of labor and compensation laws.

Comment: @CoffeeNerd: I haven’t heard of a restriction like that. A bunch of large companies like Microsoft and Intel are approved as DSOs for interns, and I would guess that they serve as sponsor for their own interns, not other companies’ interns. And in the college and university student category, many more larger colleges and universities serve as sponsors for their own J-1 students.

Comment: According to [this page](https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/current/adjustments-and-extensions/) a change of category has to be approved by the State Department, but it must be necessary due to “necessary due to unusual or exceptional circumstances”. Transfers are possible, but only within the same category. But you are allowed to enter the US 30 days before your J-1 program, right? Since your first 4 weeks are research visits that are unpaid and might be allowed for any type of visitor, perhaps you could investigate whether those activities are allowed in the pre-program grace period?